# Most recent version of Xcode which can target iOS 5.1.1 (original iPad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an old original first-gen iPad, running the latest (for it) iOS 5.1.1

I'd like to write some basic apps for it, but on my Mac I have Xcode 8, which shows the old iPad as an Unsupported Device, and I can't debug or run software on it.

I'd like to download an older version of Xcode and use that, but before I spend a lot of time on the large multi-gig download I'd like to know the best (Most recent) version of Xcode which will actually work.

Additionally, does anyone know if that version of Xcode will run on macOS Sierra, or will I need a virtual machine or something as well?

I've been unable to find the answer after significant Google searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use XCode 4.2 on OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) with an iOS 5.1 Simulator extracted from Xcode 4.3.1 (from OS X Lion) to develop apps for the old iPad and test it on the simulator. Then I move the code over to the other mac for getting it to work with the latest iOS, itunesconnect etc.

If you want to test your apps on the old device, then you will have to get a developer account on Apple and install the certificates and provisioning profile on the old machine.

If you want to actually submit the app to the app store, you will have to conform to the latest iOS (handle different cases for the deprecated classes etc etc).

> ...if that version of Xcode will run on macOS Sierra, or will I need a virtual machine

My personal preference is to get a used mac mini, set it up for a range of devices, label it, and not install any other software on it. Hardware is cheap, and new OS will always break something. "If you want to maintain legacy software support, maintain legacy hardware" is my mantra.

Hope this helps!